# postition of ticked (checked) checkbox changes after filtering data of Listview

Tags: android, listview, filter, baseadapter

I am trying to apply filter on my custom adapter which extends `BaseAdapter`, in which I am facing some problems, after I filter input based on the text in `EditText` and check the `CheckBox` to select one value and if I erase the text in the `EditText` to search for some other thing the position of the checked checkbox changes automatically as you can see in the image attached below. I am currently facing two problems

1 - Position of the ticked checkbox changes automatically

2 - If I type in uppercase in the `EditText` the `ListView` goes blank.

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
SparseBooleanArray mSparseBooleanArray;
private ArrayList<Map<String,String>> mAdapData = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
private ArrayList<Map<String,String>> mOriginalData = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

public MyCustomAdapter(Context mContext) {
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mSparseBooleanArray = new SparseBooleanArray();
}

public ArrayList<String> getCheckedItems() {
    ArrayList<String> mTempArry = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < mAdapData.size(); i++) {
        if (mSparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
            Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) mAdapData.get(i);
            final String numbr = map.get("Phone").toString();
            mTempArry.add(numbr);
        }
    }
    return mTempArry;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.mAdapData.size();
}

public void addItem(String paramString1, String paramString2) {
    Map<String, String> NameNumber = new HashMap<String, String>();
    NameNumber.put("Name", paramString1);
    NameNumber.put("Phone", paramString2);
    this.mAdapData.add(NameNumber);
    this.mOriginalData.add(NameNumber);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Object getItem(int paramInt) {
    return (ArrayList<Map<String, String>>) this.mAdapData.get(paramInt);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int paramInt) {
    return paramInt;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int paramInt, View paramView, ViewGroup paramViewGroup) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (paramView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        paramView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.multiplecontactview, null);
        viewHolder.tvName = (TextView) paramView.findViewById(R.id.txtContactName);
        viewHolder.tvNumber = (TextView) paramView.findViewById(R.id.txtContactNumber);
        viewHolder.cb = (CheckBox) paramView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        viewHolder.cb.setTag(paramInt);
        viewHolder.cb.setChecked(mSparseBooleanArray.get(paramInt));
        viewHolder.cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mCheckedChangeListener);
        viewHolder.tvName.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        viewHolder.tvNumber.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        for (int i = 0; i < mAdapData.size(); i++) {
            Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) mAdapData.get(paramInt);
            final String name = map.get("Name").toString();
            final String numbr = map.get("Phone").toString();
            viewHolder.tvName.setText(name);
            viewHolder.tvNumber.setText(numbr);
        }
        paramView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) paramView.getTag();
    }       
    return paramView;
}

OnCheckedChangeListener mCheckedChangeListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        mSparseBooleanArray.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
    }
};

public static class ViewHolder {
    TextView tvName;
    TextView tvNumber;
    CheckBox cb;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new MyContactFilter();
}

@SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
private class MyContactFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        ArrayList<Map<String, String>> mFilteredData = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(constraint)) { 
            for(int i = 0; i < mAdapData.size(); i++) {
                Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) mAdapData.get(i);
                final String names = map.get("Name").toString();
                final String numbr = map.get("Phone").toString();
                if(names.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                    Map<String, String> FilNameNumber = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    FilNameNumber.put("Name", names);
                    FilNameNumber.put("Phone", numbr);
                    mFilteredData.add(FilNameNumber);
                }
            }
            results.values = mFilteredData;
            results.count = mFilteredData.size();

        } else {
            synchronized (mOriginalData) {
                results.values = mOriginalData;
                results.count = mOriginalData.size();
            }
        }
        return results;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence cs, FilterResults fr) {
        mAdapData = (ArrayList<Map<String, String>>) fr.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Store the checked state in data itself.

Comment: @Singularity please explain what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your code more attentively, concretely on the `getView()`, you'll see that you create `ViewHolder` object every time independently of `convertView` presence.

This is wrong using of `ViewHolder` pattern. Instead of creating it everytime, create it only when `convertView` is null and set it as the tag of `convertView` by `setTag()`, otherwise get the reference to `ViewHolder` using `getTag()`.  Just Like this:

```
 ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (paramView == null) {
        paramView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.multiplecontactview, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.tvName = (TextView) paramView.findViewById(R.id.txtContactName);
        viewHolder.tvNumber = (TextView) paramView.findViewById(R.id.txtContactNumber);
        viewHolder.cb = (CheckBox) paramView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        paramView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) paramView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.cb.setTag(paramInt);
    viewHolder.cb.setChecked(mSparseBooleanArray.get(paramInt));
    viewHolder.cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mCheckedChangeListener);
    viewHolder.tvName.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    viewHolder.tvNumber.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    for (int i = 0; i < mAdapData.size(); i++) {
        Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) mAdapData.get(paramInt);
        final String name = map.get("Name").toString();
        final String numbr = map.get("Phone").toString();
        viewHolder.tvName.setText(name);
        viewHolder.tvNumber.setText(numbr);
    }
    return paramView;
```

Also in your `preformFiltering()` try to change this snippet:

`if (names.toLowerCase().contains(cs))`

to

`if (names.toLowerCase().contains(cs.toString().toLowerCase()))`

## Update

There is some strange snippet of code:

```
OnCheckedChangeListener mCheckedChangeListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        mSparseBooleanArray.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
    }
};
```

It means that if you first time check the list item which is on the 0 position in the list, than `SparseArray` indicates that the first item of the `ListView` should always have a checked box, because you don't uncheck it anywhere in you code, don't set the value to false but do it only when user manually uncheck the checkbox.

Comment: after making changes as per your edited answer, the problem started again.

Comment: And what about filtering of Uppercase letters?

Comment: that problem is now solved. but the ticked checkbox is still changing the position after re-filtering the data

Comment: I not completely understand what do you mean by "changing the position". Does it remain at the first position of the `ListView`?

Comment: hi @AlexBonel it work perfact for me but when i am Serach box clear then check box was unchecked

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of complex mappings to track properties, store the data in a class like this, along with checked state:

```
public class Data {
 private final String text;
 private boolean checked;

 public Data(String text){
   this.text = text;
   this.checked = false;
 }

 public void setChecked(boolean b){
   this.checked = b;
 }

 public boolean isChecked(){
   return this.checked;
 }

 public String getText(){
   return this.text;
 }
}
```

Inside `getView()` , set the checkbox according to data state, add listener to modify data state:

```
final Data data = getItem(position);

cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null); //important 
cb.setChecked(data.isChecked());
cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        data.setChecked(isChecked);
    }
});
```

About filtering:

`names.toLowerCase().contains(cs)`

[`Contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) does a case sensitive match, on *char values*. try `names.toLowerCase().contains(cs.toLowerCase())`

Comment: Ok thanks for the suggestion. but what you mean by this? `Store the checked state in data itself.`

Comment: @user1822826 This means `Data` class can store a `String` which is actual the text you want in list item, and a `boolean`, which is a property of that list item. use an `ArrayList<Data>` to store all `Data` objects in your adapter.

Comment: now I got it perfectly what you are trying to say. Thank you very much. can you please tell me the answer for my second question in this thread

Comment: thanks it solved the problem, but now one more problem has arises. If I type letter `T` in `EditText` the list view is getting filled with names starting with `J` and it even does not contain letter T

Comment: Apparently I found that by having { cb.setChecked(data.isChecked()) } after the setOnCheckedChangeListener to work.