# Filtering custom adapter returning incorrect results

Tags: android, filter, android-listview, baseadapter

Check:

[image: screenshot]

I am trying to implement filter on my `ListView`. But I am facing a very strange kind of problem. If I type letter `T` in the `EditText` the `ListView` is getting filled with names starting from `B` , `J`. Please help.

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
SparseBooleanArray mSparseBooleanArray;
private ArrayList<Map<String,String>> mAdapData = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
private ArrayList<Map<String,String>> mOriginalData = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

public MyCustomAdapter(Context mContext) {
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mSparseBooleanArray = new SparseBooleanArray();
}

public ArrayList<String> getCheckedItems() {
    ArrayList<String> mTempArry = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < mAdapData.size(); i++) {
        if (mSparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
            Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) mAdapData.get(i);
            final String numbr = map.get("Phone").toString();
            mTempArry.add(numbr);
        }
    }
    return mTempArry;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.mAdapData.size();
}

public void addItem(String paramString1, String paramString2) {
    Map<String, String> NameNumber = new HashMap<String, String>();
    NameNumber.put("Name", paramString1);
    NameNumber.put("Phone", paramString2);
    this.mAdapData.add(NameNumber);
    this.mOriginalData.add(NameNumber);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Object getItem(int paramInt) {
    return (ArrayList<Map<String, String>>) this.mAdapData.get(paramInt);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int paramInt) {
    return paramInt;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int paramInt, View paramView, ViewGroup paramViewGroup) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (paramView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        paramView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.multiplecontactview, null);
        viewHolder.tvName = (TextView) paramView.findViewById(R.id.txtContactName);
        viewHolder.tvNumber = (TextView) paramView.findViewById(R.id.txtContactNumber);
        viewHolder.cb = (CheckBox) paramView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        viewHolder.cb.setTag(paramInt);
        viewHolder.cb.setChecked(mSparseBooleanArray.get(paramInt));
        viewHolder.cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mCheckedChangeListener);
        viewHolder.tvName.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        viewHolder.tvNumber.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        for (int i = 0; i < mAdapData.size(); i++) {
            Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) mAdapData.get(paramInt);
            final String name = map.get("Name").toString();
            Log.e("Name", name);
            final String numbr = map.get("Phone").toString();
            Log.e("Number", numbr);
            viewHolder.tvName.setText(name);
            viewHolder.tvNumber.setText(numbr);
        }
        paramView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) paramView.getTag();
    }       
    return paramView;
}

OnCheckedChangeListener mCheckedChangeListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        mSparseBooleanArray.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
    }
};

public static class ViewHolder {
    TextView tvName;
    TextView tvNumber;
    CheckBox cb;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new MyContactFilter();
}

@SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
private class MyContactFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        ArrayList<Map<String, String>> mFilteredData = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(constraint)) { 
            for(int i = 0; i < mAdapData.size(); i++) {
                Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) mAdapData.get(i);
                final String names = map.get("Name").toString();
                final String numbr = map.get("Phone").toString();
                if(names.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                    Map<String, String> FilNameNumber = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    FilNameNumber.put("Name", names);
                    FilNameNumber.put("Phone", numbr);
                    mFilteredData.add(FilNameNumber);
                }
            }
            results.values = mFilteredData;
            results.count = mFilteredData.size();

        } else {
            synchronized (mOriginalData) {
                results.values = mOriginalData;
                results.count = mOriginalData.size();
            }
        }
        return results;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence cs, FilterResults fr) {
        mAdapData = (ArrayList<Map<String, String>>) fr.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problems come from the way you setup the `getView()` method and how you set the checked item in that SparseBooleanArray. I've edited your adapter's code and it should work now. The main changes are in the `OnCheckedChangeListener` field:

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private SparseBooleanArray mSparseBooleanArray;
    // from where do you get the data?
    private ArrayList<Map<String, String>> mAdapData = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    private ArrayList<Map<String, String>> mOriginalData = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context mContext) {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mSparseBooleanArray = new SparseBooleanArray();
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getCheckedItems() {
        ArrayList<String> mTempArry = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < mAdapData.size(); i++) {
            if (mSparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
                Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) mAdapData
                        .get(i);
                final String numbr = map.get("Phone");
                mTempArry.add(numbr);
            }
        }
        return mTempArry;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.mAdapData.size();
    }

    public void addItem(String paramString1, String paramString2) {
        Map<String, String> NameNumber = new HashMap<String, String>();
        NameNumber.put("Name", paramString1);
        NameNumber.put("Phone", paramString2);
        mAdapData.add(NameNumber);
        mOriginalData.add(NameNumber);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Object getItem(int paramInt) {
        return (ArrayList<Map<String, String>>) this.mAdapData.get(paramInt);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int paramInt) {
        return paramInt;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int paramInt, View paramView,
            ViewGroup paramViewGroup) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (paramView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            paramView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapters_specialfilterrow,
                    paramViewGroup, false);
            viewHolder.tvName = (TextView) paramView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            viewHolder.tvNumber = (TextView) paramView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            viewHolder.cb = (CheckBox) paramView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            paramView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) paramView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.cb.setTag(paramInt);
        viewHolder.cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        viewHolder.cb.setChecked(mSparseBooleanArray.get(paramInt));
        viewHolder.cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mCheckedChangeListener);
        viewHolder.tvName.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        viewHolder.tvNumber.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) mAdapData.get(paramInt);
        final String name = map.get("Name");
        final String numbr = map.get("Phone");
        viewHolder.tvName.setText(name);
        viewHolder.tvNumber.setText(numbr);
        return paramView;
    }

    OnCheckedChangeListener mCheckedChangeListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            // get the item from the current mAdapData
            Map<String, String> item = mAdapData.get((Integer) buttonView
                    .getTag());
            int position = -1;
            // see where is the item placed in the mOriginalData and use that
            // position
            for (int i = 0; i < mOriginalData.size(); i++) {
                final Map<String, String> tmp = mOriginalData.get(i);
                if (tmp.get("Name").toLowerCase().equals(item.get("Name").toLowerCase())) {
                    position = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            mSparseBooleanArray.put(position, isChecked);
        }
    };

    public static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvName;
        TextView tvNumber;
        CheckBox cb;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new MyContactFilter();
    }

    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    private class MyContactFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            ArrayList<Map<String, String>> mFilteredData = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(constraint)) {
                for (int i = 0; i < mAdapData.size(); i++) {
                    Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) mAdapData
                            .get(i);
                    final String names = map.get("Name");
                    final String numbr = map.get("Phone");
                    if (names.toLowerCase().contains(
                            constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                        Map<String, String> FilNameNumber = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        FilNameNumber.put("Name", names);
                        FilNameNumber.put("Phone", numbr);
                        mFilteredData.add(FilNameNumber);
                    }
                }
                results.values = mFilteredData;
                results.count = mFilteredData.size();
            } else {
                synchronized (mOriginalData) {
                    results.values = mOriginalData;
                    results.count = mOriginalData.size();
                }
            }
            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence cs, FilterResults fr) {
            mAdapData = (ArrayList<Map<String, String>>) fr.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: seriously , i've posted the same answer and this gets selected ... :(

Comment: @androiddeveloper Your answer was only part of the solution(which yes I included in my answer(I acknowledge that, in a comment to your answer)), but the change in the `OnCheckedChangeListener` listener was also important and finally solves all of the user's problems.

Comment: @Luksprog Hi, can you please help me with this one:                                      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020646/android-results-of-filtering-custom-adapter-are-not-reflecting-in-the-ui                                                         In my case, I am able to see filtered values on logcat. but, same changes are showing up in the UI

Answer (score 1):

in the `getView()` method , you didn't update the UI to have the values of the filtered results . 
so it returned views with old results .

just before return paramView , update the view's data to what you have in the filtered results  , and remove it from the preparation of the viewHolder , since this is called only a few times .

---

EDIT:
here's my correction of the code . i think it will fix it:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int paramInt, View paramView, ViewGroup paramViewGroup) {

ViewHolder viewHolder;

if (paramView == null) {
    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    paramView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.multiplecontactview, null);
    viewHolder.tvName = (TextView) paramView.findViewById(R.id.txtContactName);
    viewHolder.tvNumber = (TextView) paramView.findViewById(R.id.txtContactNumber);
    viewHolder.cb = (CheckBox) paramView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    viewHolder.tvName.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    viewHolder.tvNumber.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    paramView.setTag(viewHolder);
    viewHolder.cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mCheckedChangeListener);
} else {
    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) paramView.getTag();
}       
viewHolder.cb.setTag(paramInt);
viewHolder.cb.setChecked(mSparseBooleanArray.get(paramInt));


Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) mAdapData.get(paramInt);
final String name = map.get("Name").toString();
Log.e("Name", name);
final String numbr = map.get("Phone").toString();
Log.e("Number", numbr);
viewHolder.tvName.setText(name);
viewHolder.tvNumber.setText(numbr);

return paramView;
}
```

---

EDIT: 
here's a sample of how i handled the filtering :

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter()
  {
  final Filter filter=new Filter()
    {
      @Override
      protected FilterResults performFiltering(final CharSequence constraint)
        {
        _lastFilterConstraint=constraint;
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(constraint))
          return null;
        final String constraintToCheck=constraint.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        final FilterResults results=new FilterResults();
        // <- here i do the filtering itself and later put the results into "results"
        results.values=values;
        results.count=values.size();
        return results;
        }

      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      @Override
      protected void publishResults(final CharSequence constraint,final FilterResults results)
        {
        _filteredItems==null ? null : (ArrayList<Item>)results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
  return filter;
  }

@Override
public int getCount()
  {
  if(_filteredItems!=null)
    return _filteredItems.size();
  return _originalItems.size();
  }

@Override
public Item getItem(final int position)
  {
  if(_filteredItems!=null)
    {
    if(position<_filteredItems.size())
      return _filteredItems.get(position);
    return null;
    }
  if(position<_originalItems.size())
    return _originalItems.get(position);
  return null;
  }

@Override
public View getView(final int position,final View convertView,final ViewGroup parent)
  {
  final View inflatedView;
  final ViewHolder viewHolder;
  if(convertView==null)
    {
    //<- here i inflate the view into the inflatedView
    }
  else
    {
    inflaterView=convertView;
    viewHolder=(ViewHolder)inflaterView.getTag();
    }
  // <- here i use getItem and update the view according to its data .
  return inflaterView;
  }
```

Comment: but why the listview is getting filled with names containing letter B when i am searching for letter T?

Comment: @user1822826 Because you only set the `TextViews` when `convertView` is `null`(initially). Most likely the filtering shows previous rows that don't have the `TextViews` set with the new data. After you do the filtering you should look at what does `mAdapData` contains.

Comment: the convertView are recycled views for you to update . you get old views but you didn't update them . i would recommend you to watch the nice lecture of "the world of listView" by google : http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html . i think it will clear thing out.

Comment: i've also updated my answer to include the fix . hope it works now.

Comment: @user1822826 Use the code from the answer and see how the filtering behaves.

Comment: @Luksprog , thanks , didn't notice that the for loop isn't needed .

Comment: @Luksprog After making changes as per the answer above, the earlier problem arises again. The problem was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001403/postition-of-ticked-checked-checkbox-changes-after-filtering-data-of-listview

Comment: @androiddeveloper i forgot to mention that the problem mentioned in this thread is successfully solved but now the earlier problem is back.

Comment: since i don't fully understand the code and the surroundings , i would suggest to divide the handling of the data : if there is a need to filter , use only the filtered data list (in all aspects) , otherwise use the unfiltered list . it worked perfectly fine in my case.

Comment: the problem now is mentioned here ---> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001403/postition-of-ticked-checked-checkbox-changes-after-filtering-data-of-listview

Comment: well , in my code , you simply have to adjust the getCount , getItem to take the correct value . if the user is currently filtering , return the value from the filtered items , otherwise return from the original items. if you didn't understand it , i can post some code ...

Comment: ok , i've posted some new code , showing my solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

I have also implemented filter List View in my application. For that, I just need a snippet of code. Check it, if it helps.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {

            }
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                    int arg2, int arg3) {

            }
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                sendToList.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(arg0);

            }
        });
```

Comment: will this work with my adapter? i am using `ArrayList<Map<String, String>>` to fill the `listview`

Comment: Not sure, but you can try. I used it for single Object.