# Android: Results of filtering custom adapter are not reflecting in the UI

Tags: android, android-listview, filtering

In my app, I am fetching data from web server and showing the data in a list view. The adapter for my list view contains both image and text. Now,I want to filter list view. For this, I had implemented Filterable interface in my custom adapter. But, it is not giving any result. I searched alot but couldn'tcome toany result. Here's my code:

**MainActivity**

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            { 
                listMainMenu.setAdapter(mMenuAdapter);
                listMainMenu.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
                mMenuAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                pd.dismiss();
                updateUI = false;
            }//run
        };
```

**Text Watcher class**

```
_txtAutoSearch.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);

private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        Log.v(TAG+" filtertextwatcher", "afterTextChanged");
    }//afterTextChanged

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        Log.v(TAG+" filtertextwatcher", "beforeTextChanged");
    }//beforeTextChanged

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        Log.v(TAG+" filtertextwatcher", "onTextChanged");
        ((Filterable) listMainMenu.getAdapter()).getFilter().filter(s.toString());
    }//onTextChanged
};
```

**My custom adapter:**

```
    public class MainMenuAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
    Context ctx;
    ArrayList<MainCategoryDAO> mainCatDAOList;
    public static final String TAG = "MainMenuAdapter";
    ArrayList<MainCategoryDAO> arrayList;

    public MainMenuAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<MainCategoryDAO> mainCatDAOList) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.mainCatDAOList = mainCatDAOList;
    }//Constructor

    public int getCount() {
        return mainCatDAOList.size();
    }//getCount

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mainCatDAOList.get(position);
    }//getItem

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }//getItemId

    class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imgCategoryIcon;
        TextView txtCategoryName;
    }//ViewHolder

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.main_menu_adapter, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imgCategoryIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgCategoryIcon);
            holder.txtCategoryName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCategoryName);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }//if
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }//else
        Typeface cat_nameTF = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), "fonts/arial.ttf");
        Log.v(TAG, "category name "+ mainCatDAOList.get(position).getCategory_name());
        Log.v(TAG, "category icon "+ mainCatDAOList.get(position).getCategory_icon());
        BitmapManager.INSTANCE.loadBitmap(mainCatDAOList.get(position).getCategory_icon(), holder.imgCategoryIcon, 50, 50);
        holder.txtCategoryName.setTypeface(cat_nameTF);
        holder.txtCategoryName.setText(mainCatDAOList.get(position).getCategory_name());
        Log.v(TAG, "text view category name "+ holder.txtCategoryName.getText());
        return convertView;
    }//getView

    @Override
public Filter getFilter() 
{
    Filter mFilter = new Filter() 
    {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) 
        {
            Log.v(TAG+" getFilter", "publishResults called");
            arrayList = (ArrayList<MainCategoryDAO>) results.values;
            Log.v(TAG+" getFilter", "publishResults arrayList size "+arrayList.size());
            for(int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++)
            {
                Log.v(TAG+" getFilter filtered name", " "+arrayList.get(i).getCategory_name());
            }//for
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }//publishResults

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) 
        {
            Log.v(TAG+" getFilter", "performFiltering called");
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            ArrayList<MainCategoryDAO> FilteredArrList = new ArrayList<MainCategoryDAO>();

            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) 
            {
                Log.v(TAG+" getFilter", "if, constraint.length null or 0");
                results.count = mainCatDAOList.size();
                results.values = mainCatDAOList;
            }//if 
            else 
            {
                Log.v(TAG+" getFilter", "else, constraint.length not 0");
                constraint = constraint.toString();
                Log.v(TAG+" getFilter", "else, constraint = "+constraint);
                for (int i = 0; i < mainCatDAOList.size(); i++) 
                {
                    Log.v(TAG+" getFilter", "for loop, constraint.length not null or 0");
                    String data = mainCatDAOList.get(i).getCategory_name();
                    Log.v(TAG+" getFilter", "else, data to check "+data);
                    if (data.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString()))   
                    {
                        Log.v(TAG+" getFilter", "if in for loop, constraint.length not null or 0");
                        FilteredArrList.add(mainCatDAOList.get(i));
                    }//if
                }//for
                results.count = FilteredArrList.size();
                results.values = FilteredArrList;
            }//else
            return results;
        }//performFiltering
    };
    return mFilter;
}//getFilter
}//MainMenuAdapter
```

Upon testing, I found that it is filtering the result but, changes are not reflecting in listview. I even tried setting listview.setTextFilterEnabled() to true, but it also didn't worked. While on my logcat, I can see the filtered values. but not getting why the same is not reflecting in the UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's normal that you don't see any UI changes, because you aren't updating the right list of data after the filtering. Your `MainMenuAdapter` is based on the `mainCatDAOList` list of data, but in the `publishResults` method where the adapter's data should be refreshed you do:

```
arrayList = (ArrayList<MainCategoryDAO>) results.values;
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

As you can see you're updating the `arrayList` with the filtered values instead of `mainCatDAOList` so the adapter doesn't see any changes. So your code should be:

```
protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
            FilterResults results) {
        Log.v(TAG+" getFilter", "publishResults called");
        mainCatDAOList = (ArrayList<MainCategoryDAO>) results.values;
        Log.v(TAG+" getFilter", "publishResults arrayList size "+arrayList.size());
        for(int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++)
        {
            Log.v(TAG+" getFilter filtered name", " "+arrayList.get(i).getCategory_name());
        }//for
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Also you should have a copy of the initial list of data to be used for filtering, otherwise you'll not be able to return to the full set of values.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I had already fixed it. The credit goes to the answer that you had posted in the following linK http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14002421/filtering-custom-adapter-returning-incorrect-results

Comment: Sorry, for my ignorance, how does the adapter knows that  mainCatDAOList is its base list?

Comment: @user3019105 That is the list which holds the data(so any changes in the data triggers a change in the `ListView`'s rows) and also whose size is used in the `getCount()` method of the adapter(which tells the adapter how many items are in it).

Comment: So it is thanks to the constructor and the -> this.mainCatDAOList = mainCatDAOList; the OP is setting a reference to that ArrayList and when it modifies that list then the edits are reflected on the notifyDataSetChanged() called on the adapter, which uses that list to update the list items, am I right???

Comment: @user3019105 You are right. And in fact the other list, `arrayList`, it's only initialized after a filter operation is completed so it can't really be used.

Comment: I only have another question related to the constructor. Why doesn't the OP call the super() constructor of the parent BaseAdapter class to make the BaseAdapter know that that ArrayList is the one to use when notifyDataSetChanged()? Cause notifyDatasetChanged() is where the BaseAdapter applies the changes to the ArrayList, right? Maybe I am confusing something?

Comment: @user3019105 Calling `super()` will not do anything( http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/widget/BaseAdapter.java/ ). The `BaseAdapter` as its names suggest is the base class, the basic implementation of the `ListAdapter` interface on which all other adapters are based. Calling the super constructor would make sense in the case of other adapters like `ArrayAdapter` which already have an implementation, by extending `BaseAdapter` you'll have to provide an implementation on your own.

Comment: But therefore how the notifyDataSetChanged() knows that changes must be applied basing on the mainCatDAOList? Sorry, but I can't understand it, cause when I extend ArrayAdapter<T> I pass the ArrayList<T> to the super() constructor and I suppose that ArrayAdapter<T> keeps a reference to that ArrayList<T> it has received in order to call notifyDataSetChange() on it.

Comment: @user3019105 The refresh process isn't tied to the data list directly. If you follow that link you'll see that calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` triggers a call in some listeners that are registered with the adapter. That listener is registered by the widget that uses the adapter(`ListView` in this case). Following the listener notification the widget triggers some checks and updates itself(by measuring and layout) to show the new data.

Answer (score 1):

Do you add

Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

in your code? can you show your main activity code? I will help us.

Comment: Pls add,

    listMainMenu.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

in run method. Like,
Runnable r = new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            { 
                listMainMenu.setAdapter(mMenuAdapter);
                listMainMenu.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
                mMenuAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                pd.dismiss();
                updateUI = false;
            }//run
        };

Please, Let me know what is the result.

Comment: what is updateUI? is it a boolean? can you change that true in run method?