# Searching a listview when the array is in the strings xml

Tags: android, xml, arrays, listview, search

I am having an issue with my function that searches my list. The list array used to be attached to a `String[]` in the actual .java files but I moved the array into the strings xml file to implement another feature of using different languages in the app. Therefore translating the listview

Anyway, I understand why the code is doing the following but I can't work out how to solve it...

```
Resources res = getResources();
final String[] items = res.getStringArray(R.array.societies_array);

listView2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.societieslist);
EditText inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

// Adding items to listview
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
            int arg3) {
        // When user changed the Text
        System.out.println(cs);
        SocietiesScreen.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
            int arg2, int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

The onclick listener of thelist is depend on the index of the list so when not searched it works fine but when I search for a particular option the new 'first option' now gets assigned a new index number instead of keeping it's original

Hope that makes sense and I have given enough code, if you need anything else just let me know

Thanks

Comment: i'd say it makes sense that the index is the index in the displayed item, is it not ?

Comment: yeah, it kinda makes sense but if the index is the index of the whole line, it will find my error

Comment: The behavior is normal but this shouldn't be an issue as you always have the `getItem(position)` method that you could call on your adapter to get the string for that row.

Comment: @Luksprog but when I use that, like in my code it resets the position so I press the first option in the 'searched' list and it uses the data of the first option in the full list. If that makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

I think I've already answered a very similar question, [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14002625/878126). You should also watch "[**the world of listView**](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html)" lecture.

Basically, if you use a custom BaseAdapter, you can create a new mode for filtered items, which is enabled as long as there is something in the search field.

When this mode is enabled, items are retreived from a filtered list instead of from the original list.

If you don't use your own BaseAdapter, check out [**this link**](http://www.mokasocial.com/2010/07/arrayadapte-filtering-and-you/).